# Where is the .vssettings for Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio-express, vssettings

Which directory is this file located in?

Reason I ask is, I want to back up my settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Import and Export Settings**. Your settings file is saved to the directory specified by the *Automatically save my settings to this file* box.

It was `%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings` on my machine.

See How to: [Share Settings Between Computers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x6229t8(VS.80).aspx).  And yes, it's a misleadingly-named option heading.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to do this on schedule.

I suggest to specify where your settings file is and then backup that location:

1. In the Tools menu, chose Options.
2. In the Environment folder, choose Import and Export Settings
3. In Automatically save my settings to
   this file, enter the location you will backup.
4. Click OK.